# Get a root domain on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, url, path, relative-path

how can I get only the domain, for example:

The url: **http://localhost:11093/SiteA/Admin/Default.aspx**

Then, I want to get only the: **http://localhost:11093/SiteA/**

I am using:

```
Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.Host)
```

But only get the: **localhost**, and trying:

```
Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
```

But get the whole address. Thank you very much.

Comment: What about Page.ResolveUrl("~/")

Comment: @PhilBolduc: That's only get the "SiteA" part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var HostAndPath = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Uri.AbsolutePath, "")
```

Comment: Hey thanks, its work! But I've modified it become: `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "") & Page.ResolveUrl("~/")`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:11093/SiteA/Admin/Default.aspx");
string requested = uri.Scheme + uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port;
```

You can work directly on the request URI

```
Uri uri = Request.Url;
string requested = uri.Scheme + uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port;
```

Comment: No, you can get it directly from the request if you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~").ToString()
```